# AngularJS service Controller Logs undefined error for Custom Class Collection

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, service, controller

I have been trying to implement AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC and I am stuck with odd problem. I have used `$http.get()` to request to List of Custom Class `Question` but it goes to error block of angular controller.

when I return `List<sting>` it works well and doesn't log any error and shown on UI.

Here's my code:

AngularJS:

```
var BlogPostApp = angular.module('BlogPostApp', [])

BlogPostApp.controller('BlogPostController', function ($scope, BlogPostService) {
    getPosts();
    function getPosts() {
        BlogPostService.getPosts()
            .success(function (posts) {
                $scope.posts = posts;
                console.log($scope.posts);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load blog post data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    }
});

// Services
BlogPostApp.factory('BlogPostService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var BlogPostService = {};
    BlogPostService.getPosts = function () {
        return $http.get('/Editor/GetPosts');
    };
    return BlogPostService;
}]);
```

MVC Code

When I try to return `List<Question>`, it logs undefined error

```
public JsonResult GetPosts()
        {
            List<Question> posts = PostRepository.Posts(10);
            return Json(posts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Works fine with `List<string>`

```
public JsonResult GetPosts()
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst.Add("aa"); 
            lst.Add("bb");
            return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Entity Class:

```
public partial class Question
    {
        PIdbEntities db = null;
        public Question()
        {
            this.QAMaps = new HashSet<QAMap>();
            db = new PIdbEntities();
        }
        public int Id { get;set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public string Meta { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<QAMap> QAMaps { get; set; }
        public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: if you return a list<string> then it works well? you mean instead of list<question>?

Comment: @LiranBo; That's correct, The Console log shows `{ [aa],[bb] }. but not when i return JSON data with `List<Question>`

Comment: can you post ur question class

Comment: @LiranBo: I've added the Entity as well

Comment: just to be on the safe side here, did you debug and checked that `List<Question> posts = PostRepository.Posts(10);` doesn't return null or empty list? cause this looks like a json error and not anything else, since you said that regular list of string works.

Comment: @LiranBo: I actually thought so but yes, It it returning data so It's not empty or null. I first tried with an empty string `test` and later with List<string> and the it worked for both.

Comment: hmm.. just for the sake of ruling this out completely.. try adding [JsonIgnore] to all members of Question besides the Text field.
maybe it has something to do with the data...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93279/discussion-between-user2564977-and-liranbo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the JSON formatting. you questions has a self referencing loop (question -> answer -> question again).

Therefore the JSON serializer is faced with an endless loop, to fix it you can use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, don't forget to add `using Newtonsoft.Json;`.

add this `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to either model (question\answer) accordingly:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
```

or a better option in the `Answer` entity, add the attribute to the `Question` navigation property.

This way you will get the set of answer for a question and you won't get the self ref loop.